# android interface callback issue

Tags: java, android

At the moment I have got 2 class.  The main class, and the LinearLayout class that returns linearLayout

The layout class has a button and a edittext view,  and its going to bundle all up and return a view back to the main class to use it.

In the main class there will be a ArrayList that will be created here dynamically and in then end, will display them out.

Problem
I want to use QR scanner on each of button.  I passed the context to the LinearLayout class in order to create components and create the scanner on the button click. Which it works on click of each created button in the layout list and it automatically callback to the main class onActivityResult method.

But then I want to update the text view for the linearLayout that was clicked.

I don't know how to get the position of which button(linearLayout) was clicked after the callback.

I got a feeling its something to do with Callback / interface. But I don't know how to use it fully

Code of the LinearLayout is call SearchBar :

```
EditText et;
Button bt;
LinearLayout ll;
IntentIntegrator _scanner;

public SearchBar(Context c){
    et=new EditText(c);
    bt=new Button(c);
    //et.setHint("WayPoint");
    bt.setText("Scan");
    _scanner = new IntentIntegrator((Activity) c);

    ll=new LinearLayout(c);
    setLinearLayout();

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _scanner.initiateScan();
        }
    });

    et.setLayoutParams(flowLeft());
    bt.setLayoutParams(flowRight());

    ll.addView(et);
    ll.addView(bt);
}
public LinearLayout getSearchBar(){
    return ll;
}
```

Code of the main class in brief:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    //_scanner = new IntentIntegrator(this);

    //button_scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan); 

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this); 
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);        
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

    l2=new LinearLayout(this);      
    l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
    ll.addView(l2);

    //testing for searchBar class
    SearchBar origin= new SearchBar(this);
    origin.setHint("Origin");
    origin.setText("me");
    sbs.add(origin);
    ll.addView(sbs.get(0).getSearchBar());

    destin= new SearchBar(this);
    destin.setText("destin");
    destin.setHint("destination");
    destinLayout=destin.getSearchBar();
    sbs.add(destin);
    ll.addView(destinLayout);

    sv.addView(ll); 
    this.setContentView(sv);
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE) { // from Barcode Scanner
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (scanResult == null){
                //Alert.ShowAlert(this, "Scanning", "Scan Failed");
            }else {
                String scanned = scanResult.getContents();

                //How to get position of which button was fired

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `public void onClick(View v)` has the `View` parameter.  You can do whatever you want with that including `getId()` or `getParent()`.  Maybe you want to call `v.getParent()` and store that in a class variable so that you can access it in `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Its all dynamic view, so its the button and editText. The getId() always return -1,  don't seems to be working

Comment: You just need to call getParent() and store that.  Then in onActivityResult call parent.getChildAt(x) where x is the index of the editText